# Warnings after installation

Tags: theming, distributions

I have installed the Recruiter distro.
I have also installed the Respond and Selectivizr libraries under site/all/libraries.
However I still take these messages:
Warning: file_get_contents(sites/all/libraries/selectivizr/selectivizr.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in omega_build_js_cache() (line 388 of /var/www/html/recruiter/profiles/recruiter/themes/omega/omega/includes/scripts.inc).

and

Warning: file_get_contents(sites/all/libraries/respond/respond.min.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in omega_build_js_cache() (line 388 of /var/www/html/recruiter/profiles/recruiter/themes/omega/omega/includes/scripts.inc).

How can this be fixed?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check:

1. Folder and file names if they match the directory structure in the warning message
2. /var/www/html/recruiter/profiles/recruiter/themes/omega/omega/includes/scripts.inc if the selectivizer and respond directory is included or correct
3. The permissions of the folder and file